# Angular app breaks after loading local-storage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I am working on a simple `angularjs` app that creates lists and allows the user to store anything in those lists via `local-storage`. The user is able to save their list(s) and open them again at a later time from `local-storage` and continue to add items to them.

The issue is that once loaded, the user is unable to add additional items to any of the lists.

I am assuming that once the data is loaded I must not be working with the same objects.

```
  this.saveLists = function() {
    localStorage["lists"] = JSON.stringify(this.lists);
  };

  this.loadLists = function() {
    this.lists = JSON.parse(localStorage['lists']);
  };
```

I've created an example over at [plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/TADx1HjpeOsmqbHgyAW2?p=preview)

Is this happening because I first stringified the array and then parsed it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you JSON stringify an array, you lose the addValue function.  I modified your plunker to show the JSON.stringified list below the buttons (you can see that the addValue function is missing):

[image]

So when the lists are saved and reloaded, the list data is restored, but the 'addValue' function is not.

To make this work, you can move the addValue function to your controller:

```
app.controller('TempController', function($scope) {      
  ...    
  this.addValue = function(list, value){
    list.values.push(value);
  }      
}
```

And hook up ng-click in the HTML:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="tmpCtrl.addValue(list, valueTyped);valueTyped = ''">
     Add Value
</button>
```

Here is a Working [Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ppfoSE28degKD6QtIPQL?p=preview)